# IdentityServer4 ValidIssuers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Is there any way to tell IdentityServer4's authentication system to allow multiple issuers for the tokens?

I have an application that is using Identity Server to issue bearer tokens, and as long as the front end and the back end use the same URL to get tokens from authentication works fine.

However, I now have a need to have the same site accessed through multiple CNAMEs, meaning that the client will request tokens from two different URLs.

The error that is sent to the logs is:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware[7]
>
> > Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'http://domainb.com'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'http://domaina.com' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'null'.

The presence of a ValidIssuers collection seems to indicate that you can set multiple places from which the API will accept tokens, but I cannot find anything like that exposed in options exposed by UseIdentityServerAuthentication.

I am aware of the Authority option, but that only allows me to set a single valid authority.

Is there are any way of setting multiple valid issuers, or setting it to use something other than the hostname as the issuer id?

**UPDATE**

My identity server configuration on the server side looks like this:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(options => { 
                             options.IssuerUri = "http://authserver"; })
     .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

this is from the auth server side of things.

On the client API, the UseIdentityServerAuthentication call looks like this:

```cs
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Authority = AppSettingsConfigurationRoot["Authentication:AuthorityEndpoint"],
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ApiName = "rqapi",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    ClaimsIssuer = "http://localhost:5001"
});
```

The address in the {{AppSettingsConfigurationROot["Authentication:AuthorityEndpoint"] is usually set at the public DNS name of the server so that the token issuer as seen by AngularJS matches the URL of the IdentityServer from the point of view of the C# API.

Comment: Can you please include your `.AddIdentityServer()` configuration from your Identity Server.

Comment: I've added that to the question - thanks!

Comment: Remove the `IssuerUri` in your options.  The docs state that the Issuer name will be inferred from the request when it is not provided.

Comment: It will - but if I do that then it will work for one CNAME (as long as the API calls the auth service with the same name that the Angular JS app used through the /token endpoint. The other CNAME will throw the invalid issuer error because it's getting a certificate from the 1st CNAME, but expecting one from the 2nd CNAME.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `ClaimsIssuer` and setting all your CNAME's in `ValidIssuers`?

Comment: @Brad, I couldn't find ValidIssuers in the settings for IdentityServer4's client. I did however solve this (I will write an answer shortly) by replacing the IdentityServerAuthentication with Microsoft's own implementation (which I believe that IdentityServer uses in the background) at which point I could set the ValidIssuers, and that did work for me.

Comment: @RichardComish How did you solve it?

Comment: I think what @RichardComish did is something like this: https://github.com/microsoft/TailwindTraders-Backend/blob/b47d2e3f17c50f32985ad439c61165ec5c45a49c/Source/ApiGWs/Tailwind.Traders.WebBff/Startup.cs#L55 . This would work if the API is under your control. It can become problematic if you have multiple APIs, possibly maintained by multiple teams and on different technologies.

Answer (score 7):

As [Original Poster wrote in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950579/identityserver4-validissuers#comment86977744_49950579), the (now, 2020, deprecated) [IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation package](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation) doesn't expose the right options. To read more about the recent deprecation [check this blogpost](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/07/06/flexible-access-token-validation-in-asp-net-core/), but if you still are using it, here's how I solved this issue.

[The `AddIdentityServerAuthentication(...)` extension method](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/blob/8a6bd7ebafc31a76068a9b6863eec94739ec2990/src/IdentityServerAuthenticationExtensions.cs#L52-L70) is a wrapper (the code is super readable!) to combine *two* authentication schemes:

1. JwtBearer
2. OAuth2Introspection

It uses its own configuration class, and simply doesn't expose all the `JwtBearer` options (possibly just an omission, possibly because some options are not valid for *both* schemes.

**If -like me- you only need JwtBearer** you might get away with simply using just that, and using the `ValidIssuers` array. So:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://example.org";
        options.Audience = "foo-api"; // options.ApiName in the IDS4 variant
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuers = new[]
            {
                "https://example.org", // first issuer
                "https://example.com", // some other issuer
            },
            NameClaimType = "name", // To mimick IDS4's variant
            RoleClaimType = "role", // To mimick IDS4's variant
        };
    });
```

As far as I understand, this will use `example.org` as the *Authority* and get the openid-configuration and so forth from that domain. But any JWT token offered to this API would be accepted as long as *one* of the `ValidIssuers` is the `iss` (issuer claim) in the token.

Comment: It works like this, but must authority be the first entry of the issuers? What's the difference between authority and issuer anyway?

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. And am interested in the answer to liang's question, if anyone knows.